# How do I only update one value of my reducer in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Below is my code

```
function customMsg(state, action) {
state = state || {
    person: {
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false, 
        name: "",
        height: "",
    }
};

switch(action.type) {

    case ACTION_TYPES.PERSON.FETCH_PERSOn_CONTENT_SUCCESS:
        return $.extend({}, state, {
            person.name: action.result.name
        });

    default: 
        return state;
}
}
```

How do I only update one value of my reducer in Redux? 
Above is a example which i only want to update the name of person object.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using jQuery extend, create a clone and set person name:

```
var newState = $.extend({}, state);
newState.person.name = action.result.name;
return newState;
```

Otherwise, to clone deeply an object you can use [lodash cloneDeep()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#cloneDeep).

Another way is to use [immutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) to set your app state as immutable. It is much more bug "mutable" proof and offers functions to set deep nested value in an immutable. See [updateIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/updateIn):

```
return state.updateIn(['person', 'name'], () => action.result.name);
```

Try it!